# $errorAction-Preference=" Stop" is working in PowerShell ISE but not working on PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

`$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`  is working fine in PowerShell ISE but not working on PowerShell.
Even `-ErrorAction Stop` is not working

Comment: Are the typos just here in your question or do you misstype it in your console as well? The name is `$ErrorActionPreference` and `-ErrorAction Stop`  ... please notice: no dash in the variable name but a dash in front of the parameter name!!  ;-)

Comment: yes i write these commands just wrongly typed in question

Comment: So you might first take [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to set you up how to use SO and you might (re)read the help [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  ... and you might fix your typos in your question as well.

Comment: Please explain "not working". Does it give u error? After setting the value, does it not actually set?

Comment: no it is showing the error in red lines in powershell but does not exit from there